# Como saber si una hora esta entre un intervalo de tiempo dentro de un arreglo

Tags: javascript, html, angular

tengo varios intervalos de horas en un arreglo, ejemplo

```
[
    {abre: "08:00", cierra: "13:00"},
    {abre: "14:00", cierra: "16:00"}
]
```

asi obtengo mi hora actual

```
var today = new Date()
var actualDay = today.getDay()

var hour = new Date('1/1/1999 ' + `${today.getHours()}:${today.getMinutes()}`);
```

y necesito mostrar una vista en el HTML bien sea Abierto o Cerrado

he intentado recorrer el arreglo asi

```
horario.forEach(item => {

        var open = new Date('1/1/1999 ' + item.open);
        var close = new Date('1/1/1999 ' + item.close);
        


        if ( hour >= open && close >= hour) {
          let abierto = document.getElementById("abierto") as HTMLElement
          abierto.innerHTML = "ABIERTO"
          return
        } else {
          let cerrado = document.getElementById("cerrado") as HTMLElement
          cerrado.innerHTML = "CERRADO"
          return
        }
      });
```

pero me devuelve la vista "ABIERTO" "CERRADO" es decir ambos,

tambien cree variables booleanas para recorrer el array de esta manera

```
horario.forEach(item => {

        var open = new Date('1/1/1999 ' + item.open);
        var close = new Date('1/1/1999 ' + item.close);
     


        if ( hour >= open && close >= hour) {
          this.cerrado = false
          this.abierto = true
        } else {
          this.abierto = false
          this.cerrado = true
        }
      });
    }
```

Pero al hacer esto siempre termina evaluando la ultima posicion del arreglo,

alguna idea?

Comment: No entiendo para qué tienes 2 variables this.abierto y this.cerrado. Con 1 variable this.estado que cuando esté a true signifique que está abierto y que cuando esté a false signifique que está cerrado te sobraría.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es que salga la etiqueta "ABIERTO" si está en alguno de los rangos de hora. Y si no mostrar "CERRADO".

Para eso te basta con crear una variable booleana que únicamente se activa si encuentra un rango en el que esté incluida la hora:

```js
const horario = [
    {open: "08:00", close: "13:00"},
    {open: "14:00", close: "16:00"}
];

function isOpen(hour) {
  let opened = false;
  horario.forEach(item => {
    let open = new Date('1/1/1999 ' + item.open);
    let close = new Date('1/1/1999 ' + item.close);
    opened = opened || ( hour >= open && close >= hour);
  });
  return opened;
}

const testHours = [
  "07:30", "08:30", "14:30", "15:30", "19:00"
];

testHours.forEach(hour => {
  const hourDate = new Date(`1/1/1999 ${hour}`);
  console.log(hour, isOpen(hourDate) ? 'ABIERTO' : 'CERRADO');
});
```